# Cannot get F# Chiron Json serializer working on Linux

Tags: linux, f#, mono, visual-studio-code

I cannot get [Chiron](https://github.com/xyncro/chiron) Json serializer working on Elementary OS with VS Code.

On Windows it works as I tested it. On MacOS it works as well if I recall correctly.

Here is the minimal not-working solution:

This is the script file `App.fsx`:

```
#load "paket-files/include-scripts/net46/include.chiron.fsx"

open Chiron

printfn "%A" (Object <| Map.ofList [ "foo", String "bar" ] |> Json.format)
```

This is the `paket.dependencies` file:

```
source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
nuget Chiron
```

Include scripts have to be generated. Either from IDE or by executing `mono ./paket/paket.exe generate-include-scripts`.

When I run `fsharpi App.fsx` I get the following error:

```
/tmp/test/stdin(0,1): error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'FParsecCS.dll' in any of
 /usr/lib/mono/4.5
 /tmp/test/./packages
 /tmp/test
 /usr/lib/cli/fsharp/
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Escaping' threw an exception.
  at Chiron+Formatting+formatObject@728-1.Invoke (System.Tuple`2[T1,T2] tupledArg) [0x0000f] in <57e2953614a049a0a74503833695e257>:0 
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult].InvokeFast[V] (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] func, T arg1, TResult arg2) [0x00018] in <566a0818dff9fae1a745038318086a56>:0 
  at Chiron+Formatting+join@667-2[a].Invoke (System.Text.StringBuilder b) [0x00029] in <57e2953614a049a0a74503833695e257>:0 
  at Chiron+Formatting+join@666-1[a].Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[T] values, System.Text.StringBuilder b) [0x00013] in <57e2953614a049a0a74503833695e257>:0 
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.OptimizedClosures+Invoke@3252[T2,TResult,T1].Invoke (T2 u) [0x00001] in <566a0818dff9fae1a745038318086a56>:0 
  at Chiron+Formatting+formatObject@726-6.Invoke (System.Text.StringBuilder x) [0x00013] in <57e2953614a049a0a74503833695e257>:0 
  at Chiron+Formatting+formatObject@726-7.Invoke (System.Text.StringBuilder x) [0x00001] in <57e2953614a049a0a74503833695e257>:0 
  at Chiron+Formatting+formatObject@726-8.Invoke (System.Text.StringBuilder x) [0x00001] in <57e2953614a049a0a74503833695e257>:0 
  at Chiron+Formatting+Json.format (Chiron+Json json) [0x00013] in <57e2953614a049a0a74503833695e257>:0 
  at <StartupCode$FSI_0001>.$FSI_0001.main@ () [0x00046] in <6e3acc116b9749ea9b5dc27663d21170>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
Stopped due to error
```

If you are not on Linux, the error can be reproduced with docker like this:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/tmp/ttt fsharp/fsharp bin/bash
```

### Update

Also referencing the assemblies directly does not work:

```
#r "packages/Aether/lib/net35/Aether.dll" 
#r "packages/FParsec/lib/net40-client/FParsecCS.dll"
#r "packages/FParsec/lib/net40-client/FParsec.dll"
#r "packages/Chiron/lib/net40/Chiron.dll" 

open Chiron

printfn "%A" (Object <| Map.ofList [ "foo", String "bar" ] |> Json.format)
```

Comment: Maybe you can try using [Fleece](https://github.com/mausch/Fleece) and see if it works on that environment. If it works you'll see that it's basically the same project, although both are based in Aeson, Chiron seems to have copied lot of code and ideas from Fleece without quoting it.

Comment: Fleece is not the same project though. Chiron did quote Fleece when it was released a few years back. +1 on Chiron rather than Fleece as chiron is continuously updated.

Comment: Thanks @Henrik but I wonder what's the point of copying a project instead of cloning and contributing back to the original. Did a PR got rejected? If the approach is the same, why duplicate efforts?

Comment: The approach is not identical. The point is that mausch doesn't maintain Fleece due to private reasons.

Comment: Could it be that Elementary (based on older ubuntu) needs a newer mono, than whichever default repo provides? Try adding mono repo and upgrading from there.

Comment: @EugeneTolmachev Ok, I'll check that. The error can also be reproduced using the F# docker image (https://github.com/fsprojects/docker-fsharp/blob/57b3ddadc85a63bf586ab89b523bb8326dad9c12/4.0.1.1/Dockerfile). But it could be the same problem there as well. It's mono version 4.4.2.11. (I'm running 4.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include:

```
 #r "packages/FParsec/lib/net40-client/FParsecCS.dll"
 #r "packages/FParsec/lib/net40-client/FParsec.dll"
```

Too.

You may have run into [this issue](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/484)

Comment: Hi @Henrik, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this does not solve the issue. The generated include script does exactly this. If I reference the assemblies manually (in this order `Aether.dll`, `FParsecCS.dll`, `FParsec.dll`, `Chiron.dll`) I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is missing for you, but using `fsharp` docker container I was able to run it:

```
#I "packages/FParsec/lib/net40-client/"
- #I "packages/Aether/lib/net35/"     
- #I "packages/Chiron/lib/net40/";;

--> Added '/root/packages/FParsec/lib/net40-client/' to library include path


--> Added '/root/packages/Aether/lib/net35/' to library include path


--> Added '/root/packages/Chiron/lib/net40/' to library include path

> #r "Chiron.dll";;

--> Referenced '/root/packages/Chiron/lib/net40/Chiron.dll' (file may be locked by F# Interactive process)

> open Chiron
- 
- printfn "%A" (Object <| Map.ofList [ "foo", String "bar" ] |> Json.format);;
Binding session to '/root/packages/FParsec/lib/net40-client/FParsecCS.dll'...
Binding session to '/root/packages/FParsec/lib/net40-client/FParsec.dll'...
"{"foo":"bar"}"

val it : unit = ()
```